# Datapump export

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sql-developer, datapump

I'm trying to export the full database using the datapump API, I tried to use this following code:

```
DECLARE
handle NUMBER;

nom_job varchar(25) := to_char(SYSDATE,'YYYYMMDD_HH24MISS');
nom_dump varchar(25) := nom_job || '.dmp';
nom_log varchar(25) := nom_job || '.log';

BEGIN
handle := SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP.OPEN(

    operation => 'EXPORT',
    job_mode  => 'FULL',
    job_name  => nom_job

    );

SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE(

    handle    => handle,
    filename  => nom_dump,
    directory => 'C:\Backup_folder',
    filetype  => 1

);

SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE(

    handle    => handle,
    filename  => nom_log,
    directory => 'C:\Backup_folder',
    filetype  => 3

);

SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP.START_JOB(

    handle => handle,
    skip_current => 0,
    abort_step => 0

);

SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP.DETACH(

    handle=> handle

);

END;
```

But it gives me this next error:

```
ORA-39001: valeur d'argument non valide
ORA-06512: à "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", ligne 79
ORA-06512: à "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", ligne 2926
ORA-06512: à "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", ligne 3162
ORA-06512: à ligne 21
39001. 00000 -  "invalid argument value"
*Cause:    The user specified API parameters were of the wrong type or
           value range.  Subsequent messages supplied by
           DBMS_DATAPUMP.GET_STATUS will further describe the error.
*Action:   Correct the bad argument and retry the API.
```

the line 21 is :

```
SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE(
```

Where is the problem exactly in that function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Argument 'Directory' of the ADD_FILE procedure, i should specify the name  of the directory created by the next command instead of the actual path:

```
create directory backup_folder as 'C:\backup_folder'
```

PS: the name of the directory specified in ADD_FILE should be in upper case (CAPITAL LETTERS).